# Node-js: sendgrid - cannot create production build

Tags: node.js, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

When i try to generate a production build to deploy my react App i get this error:

```
Creating an optimized production build...
Failed to compile.

static/js/main.709a793f.js from UglifyJs
SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (EmailAddress) [./~/@sendgrid/helpers/classes/email-address.js:11,0]
```

I think this error is caused by the Sendgrid NPM package.
I tried to reinstall Sendgrid via npm and verified that there is no missing dependencies.

-> % npm -v
6.2.0

-> % node -v
v10.8.0

Thank you in advance